# How can I extract a word from a variable?

Tags: python, edx

I'm taking MIT 6.00.1x from edX.org and I'm on problem set 1 problem 2. I'm having trouble getting bob from this variable

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
```

I have this code

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
bobTimes = 0

for bobWord in s:
  if 'b' and 'o' and 'b' in bobWord:
    bobTimes += 1

print(bobTimes)
```

The code works for this variable, but when you add on another b and o, like this:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghaklbobddbtto'
```

It adds one to the `bobTimes` variable. I don't see how I can extract the word 'bob' from this variable.

Comment: The code does not work: your code only counts the number of times `b` is in `s`: `if 'b' and 'o':` will always succeed.

Comment: I meant that it works for that variable, sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Why don't you just use the built in string matching `s.find('bob')` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't work for that variable It gives the answer three, which is the number of times 'b' is in that string. "bob" is only present once or twice, depending on whether you allow overlapping matches.

Comment: you are trying to count the number of `bob` in `s` right ?

Answer (score 0):

Just get the next 3 characters of the string using python's list slices.

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl' #prints 2
s = 'azcbobobegghaklbobddbtto' #prints 3
bobTimes = 0

for i in range(len(s)):
  if s[i:i+3] == 'bob':
    bobTimes += 1

print(bobTimes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify the extraction requirements? Specifically:

is `bobob` two bobs, or just one? is `bobobob` three? or must they all be seperate i.e. `bobasdfbobwwwwbob`

`s.count("bob")` would count how many instances of "bob" occur with non overlapping letters. i.e `bob` is 1, `bobbob` is 2, `bobob` is only one because the middle b only counts towards the first one, leaving only `ob`, but `bobobob` is 2 better read as `bob o bob`

you could iterate through the characters one at a time, and check if that character and the next 3 are equal to "bob"

```
for k,v in enumerate(s):
   if s[k:k+3]=="bob": bobcount+=1
```

this approach counts `bobob` as two, and `bobobob` as three.
or you could resort to using regular expressions, but thats not my strong suit, and i'll leave that to someone else to explain/update a bit later with info on that.